# Sending RealTime Notifications Based on Location in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m building an app with some location-based requirements. One of the requirements is to send the user a notification whenever the user is at a specific address (think of it like how the Apple Wallet app sends you a notification whenever you get close to, say a Starbucks location).

How would I go about building this kind of functionality? I’m aware that this will require using WebSockets. But, like, how would I do this exactly?

Do I just have the client send his geo coordinates to my backend every time it changes, then compare that to a desired destination saved on a database? Or, is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a perfect job for WebWorkers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Hmm. Okay that works. Thanks